# C program links to wrong version of function

Tags: c, linker, glibc

I'm trying to debug an issue where the wrong version of a function gets called causing a segfault.  The code that I'm compiling is machine generated and includes a function called 'times' that does a complex multiply of it's two arguments.  This code is compiled to a .o before being linked into a higher level object file.

When run this code segfaults and gdb indicates that it's in glibc's version of 'times' which doesn't even take the same number of arguments.  The are no instances of '#include  anywhere in this code.

Changing the name of times to times1 resolves the problem.  This isn't a long term solution though due to the machine generated nature of the code and manually editing the name of this function all the time is unappealing.

The whole mess compiles cleaning with -Wall so I'm not sure where to look.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
Compile chain:
    gcc -Wall -I. -g --shared -o dpd.o -fPIC *.c (mahine generated code here)
    gcc -g --std=c99 -c -fpic getData.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lmatio -I/usr/local/include/iverilog -I$(MATLAB)
    gcc -g -shared -o getData.vpi getData.o $(MATLAB)/dpd.o -lvpi -lmatio -L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: It's not conventional to compile multiple C files to a single `.o`.  If `times.c` is one among several C files compiled in this group, it could explain the problem.

Comment: An `#include` only brings in declarations; it has no control over linking.  If you declare a function called `times` and then call it, the compiler will produce an object file that contains a reference to that name in its symbol table, and then the linker will search for a definition of that name when producing the final executable.  There's a `times` function in libc, and that's what the linker found.

Comment: Gene - Could you elaborate on your comment?  times.c is indeed a seperate C file which is compiled into that single object.  Why would you expect this to cause a problem?  There is really only one entry point I'm interested in for this .o and 'times' is not one of them.  i.e. it should be totally internal and not seen as a dynamic symbol to higher layers.  Is there a way to tell gcc about this?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear.  The line `gcc --shared ... *.c ...` does not make sense to build a `.o` file.  The glob `*.c` will capture all the `.c` files in the directory.  The `-shared` option is normally to build a shared libary, which is a `.so` file in Linux or a `.dll` in Windows versions of `gcc`.  I don't know what `--shared` would do.  Maybe nothing.  You want a command like `gcc -c times.c` and similar for each other generated file.  Then link all the resulting `.o` files in the final command.

Comment: Brian, is there any significance in `dpd.o` being prefixed by `$(MATLAB)/` in the link line but not in the compile line?  Also could you try `-nodefaultlibs`?

Comment: Another thing, why are you linking libraries in both the 2nd and third lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the real answer to this one is to throw `-fno-builtin-times` to gcc.  That avoids the problem neatly with no fuss.

This of course assumes that you can't changes the name of `times` to something that doesn't conflict with a glibc provided function.

Answer (score 3):

C only uses the name of a function as an identifier, so any two (exported) functions with the same name will conflict. The normal approch is to prefix all exported names in a library with a unique prefix. The other alternative is to use C++ as "a better C" and simply build your C code using a C++ compiler, making use of C++ name mangling.

Comment: Shouldn't in this case the linker choke with "duplicate symbol"?

Comment: Not unless you force it to drag in two different .o files with the same symbol in them.

Comment: @H2CO3 UNIX linkers *never* complain when the same symbol is defined in the main executable and in a shared library (`libc.so.6` here) - such symbol interpositioning is quite common and often very useful.